# change hyperlink image on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Hi I'm trying to change the image of hyperlink on-click as follows. But the image of the select button is not changing to loading.gif. What am I doing wrong? I'm new to jquery. Thanks in anticipation

```
 <HTML><HEAD>
    <SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="jquery.js"></SCRIPT>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
    <TABLE>
    <TBODY>
    <TR>
    <TD><A id=webservice_submit href="javascript:document.frm_correction.submit()" jQuery1365443220846="2">
        <IMG onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Correction subj','','http://localhost:6868/corrmgr/img/select_up.gif',0)" onmouseout=MM_swapImgRestore() name="Correction Subj" alt="Correction Subj" src="http://localhost:6868/corrmgr/img/select.gif" oSrc="http://localhost:6868/corrmgr/img/select.gif"> 
         </A></TD></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>
    <DIV style="DISPLAY: none" id=loading jQuery1365443220846="3"><IMG name="Please wait..." alt="Please wait while the request is being processed..." src="http://localhost:6868/corrmgr/img/bert2.gif"> </DIV>
    <SCRIPT language=javascript>  
        var $loading = $('#loading'); 

        $('#webservice_submit').click(function(){     
            $loading.toggle();    
            if( $loading.is(':visible') ){
                alert("invoking web services");
                $('#image img').attr('src', 'http://localhost:63531/corrmgr/img/loading.gif');
                return ($(this).attr('disabled')) ? false : true;          
            }
        }); 

        $('#loading').hide(); 
    </SCRIPT>
    </BODY></HTML>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to assign the Loader Image to the below image tag

```
<IMG name="Please wait..." alt="Please wait while the request is being processed..." 
src="http://localhost:6868/corrmgr/img/bert2.gif">
```

If i have understand you... you change your code like below...

**FROM :**

```
$('#image img').attr('src', 'http://localhost:63531/corrmgr/img/loading.gif');
```

**TO :**

```
$("img[name='Please wait...']").attr('src', 'http://localhost:63531/corrmgr/img/loading.gif');
```

Comment: Thanks Pandian. The loader was one way that I was trying. I have tried that too and it still doesn't work. Here's the modified code: $('#webservice_submit').click(function(){     
     $loading.toggle();    
     if( $loading.is(':visible') ){
      alert("invoking web services");
      $('img[name='Please wait...').attr('src', 'http://localhost:63531/corrmgr/img/loading.gif');          
     }
 });

Answer (score 3):

Your selector is not right. Change this:

```
$('#image img')
```

to this:

```
$('#image')
```

And give `<img>` the corresponding `id`:

```
<IMG id="image" ...>
```

Comment: Hi Adrian, Thanks for the reply. I've now changed the code as below but for no avail.

Comment: Sorry, I can't provide the modified code (size limit). Here's the chunk that I changed. <IMG id="wsselect" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Correction subj' ........) and in the javascript - $('#wsselect').attr('src', 'http://localhost:63531/corrmgr/img/loading.gif');